# Entity Framework - Common Query

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

referencing at previous post ([Entity Wrapper - Custom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496713/entity-wrapper-custom))
I still have some difficult about generic query to retrieving common field.

I've a simple interface with one field only. All my entities inheritance from my interface. Then I've a class encapsulating my objectContext typed.
Well, now I need to execute a linq query to get my IQuerable object.
 The following snippet goes on error at building time:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetQuery<T>() where T : IEntity 
{
    var query =
        GetObjectSetSomehow; //problem: I don't know the objectSet type here!!   
    return query.Where(p => p.field == "..."); 
}
```

But especially my issue is about impossibility to make casting from IQuerable where T : MyInterface to ObjectSet

Any suggestion wiil be appreciated..

Comment: Please format the code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383062.aspx) could help you. As MSDN says, Method

> Creates a new ObjectSet
>   instance that is used to query, add,
>   modify, and delete objects of the
>   specified entity type.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Create<T>(ObjectContext context) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        var query = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AsQueryable();
        return query.Where(x => true);
    }
```